# Modify bitrix self-hosted crm search results

Tags: bitrix

I've created a custom CRM component in Bitrix and placed it in the local folder. The global search and CRM search, however, does not search field values in this custom component.

How / where would I modify the search module to include the custom component?

Any pointers would be useful.

Thanks,
Jesal

Comment: Search module not using component as content source.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. How can I extend the search module to include component in content source? Will adding to b_search_content help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component usually hasn't content for search.Look at [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Component is a controller.  All content in a model. In bitrix case your model it's iblock module. For add iblock elements to search module you need go to iblock settings and set checkbox "
Index elements for the Search module" http://joxi.ru/D2P8vgKspx4RQ2

After that you need reindex all data on page /bitrix/admin/search_reindex.php?lang=en. http://joxi.ru/eAODvELfxbqDdr

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that helps.